# event to place without

Tags: meaning

Example ([Russia Slides Back to the Middle Ages](http://www.thedailybeast.com/articles/2015/08/07/russia-slides-back-to-the-middle-ages.html)):

> It is rare in modern Russia for a public or political event **to place without the church present**. In the insurgent Donetsk and Luhansk regions of Ukraine, priests bless armed rebel soldiers going to war against Kiev. Some experts have compared the Russian president to Slobodan Milosevic, the former Serbian leader, who also surrounded himself with priests.

What does the verb *place* mean in the context of that sentence? I looked it up, but I don't think I could see which meaning fitted the context best.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's about a typo/missing word *(to **take** place)*.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Honestly, this looks like someone just missed the word "take" it probably should read:

> It is rare in modern Russia for a public or political event to take place without the church present. In the ...